save email attachments in a folder under the subject name of this email
I have a huge request for help.
I would like to automate saving attachments from received emails w outlook. Now I do it manually:

message with attachments
copy the message subject
paste into notepad
replace "illegal characters" in it, e.g. "/"
back to the news
click save all attachments
create a folder with the copied name as the subject of the email (no longer allowed characters)
saves to this folder on disk
next message.

Can this be automated somehow? I will be very grateful
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GW5iUV2rRGQ

Have you had a go at using PowerAutomate? Its a citizen tool

Have you had a go at using PowerAutomate? Its a citizen tool after all.
